# Can two or more PHP frameworks be used together?

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, frameworks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using multiple php frameworks on one website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786649/using-multiple-php-frameworks-on-one-website)

I want to start building a web application for the first time. I'm good in PHP at least but wanted to use a framework (please don't discourage me).
I've searched about most PHP Frameworks and found that Zend and CodeIgniter were the best for my project.
Can I use two or more frameworks together in the same web app? If yes, what are the advantages and disadvantages??... 
Pls help!

Comment: If you use Laravel 4 - you will be able to use 'composer' components - thus picking bits and pieces of code that suits yourself

Answer (score 1):

I think nobody ought to discourage you from using a framework : it will save you a LOT of trouble eventhough it introduces a small amount of complexity. See for example http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html for details :) (yes, I like symfony).

Now most serious frameworks being well designed they can allow you to use parts of other well designed frameworks (I think symfony uses bits from zend). That being said, frameworks are somewhat complicated and I'd say you're better off using only one at a time and *maybe* expand later if absolutely necessary.

Comment: I really dont know why this topic is closed!
The other topic discusses using different subdomains for different frameworks...
I mean, can two or more frameworks be used at once in the same web app? If not why??