# can i use multiple php frameworks for a same site?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Actually, I've sub folder named **'portfolio'** (http://www.mysite.com/`portfolio`) & for that folder i'm using codeigniter but for the root directory of my site (http://www.mysite.com) i want to use laravel framework and angular.js ?

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/11786649/1723893

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plany any shared functionality between the portfolio and the rest of your site (like a common login system for example), there's no problem with using two different frameworks. All you need is a `.htaccess` file rewriting all `portfolio` requests to CodeIgniter's front controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is no problem, you only have to separate the requests on the webserver level so that some go to the Laravel framework, and some other go to the Codeigniter part.

Don't expect support inside the framework, though. It's a special solution for your special case. You have to know how to use rewriting URLs with your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with url-rewriting and set it up properly, especially for your main site (cancel rewriting for your /portfolio/ folder). Many sites uses Wordpress for their blogs, but another framework/script for main site.