# Execute Symfony project from other project

Tags: php, symfony, yii

I have one project in Yii 1, but i wan't develop some features in other framework, i choose Symfony.

The startpoint of website is a index.php from Yii1, but I build a selector by route to start one project in Yii1 or another proyect Symfony.

But when I include web/app.php i have this error:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /vagrant/planetahuerto/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Bundle/Bundle.php on line 224
```

I use this code to load symfony project:

```
<?php
chdir("../planetahuerto/web/");
require 'app.php';
exit;
```

But i don't know why Kernel Bundle didn't throw this error.

Thx.

Comment: Someone ask but no answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786649/using-multiple-php-frameworks-on-one-website

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this is by adding Http redirection in your .htaccess file.
For this to work you'll need to choose a specific route prefix for your Symfony URLs

Exp:

```
RedirectMatch seeother ^/new$ /sf-project/
```

you can find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory)

Comment: If you make a RedirectMatch, it change url , I think i don't explain very well the problem.
- urlWithString -> load sf project
- rest of url's -> load yii project.

I don't want change url.

Comment: RedirectMatch should not change your URL
you can see here https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/

Comment: I probe whit Redirect, but SF the have same error that when I load with php.